# SMB jcifs "jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled=true" impacts

Tags: java, smb, jcifs, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I had a performance issue with SMB file upload using JCIFS SMB. The problem was related to `jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled` property and using `true` fixed the issue.

Now the question is that in which case I will be having problems using `jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled=true` as it has to be static property for me? I have many different environments which is using the same configuration.

Properties document ([link](https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/overview-summary.html#scp)) says:

> If this property is true, domain based DFS referrals will be disabled.
>   The default value is false. This property can be important in
>   non-domain environments where domain-based DFS referrals that normally
>   run when JCIFS first tries to resolve a path would timeout causing a
>   long startup delay (e.g. running JCIFS only on the local machine
>   without a network like on a laptop).

... but this is over my head, cannot understand.

Also, if I could change that dynamically, what is the indication that I need to do that? Any specific Exception or scenario that points out that `true` or `false` is needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)) - what is DFS.

- In general you can mount your folder to a different share.
  For example PC1 has Share1 and the PC2 Share2 had a folder named "not located here" and it points to PC1 Share1 (just a link).

To resolve the real location The SMB uses an IOCL query "get_referrals" and this is the implementation of the DFS.